# Wierd chess-like pattern on cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Wierd chess like pattern appeared on my cycles render view and even stays in the actual final rendered image.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This chess-like pattern means transparency. You have activated Transparent in Film section of render settings.
[image: Transparency]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked.